# Trying to understand ViewController focus for Firebase screen_view event

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

We're trying to track the amount of time that users view each screen, but it looks like a container viewcontroller is being timed instead of the child viewcontroller we'd like to. I think the issue is that the container view controller has focus instead of child view controller, how to I give the child VC focus in order to trigger the Firebase screen_view timer?

Comment: That's a broad question; it depends on how your app was coded, and are you automatically tracking screens or manually within the viewDidAppear event?

Comment: I'm just using the automatic Firebase screen tracking (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews)

Comment: Again, clarity is key here on SO. Are you using separate UIViewControllers for each screen you want to track? If not, it needs to be done manually. If so, then the screen_view events will be logged, as long as each controller has focus. If you have controllers that are not getting focus, there's the issue and you need to determine why. If you don't know that then we need to see the code of how the controllers are instantiated and being used. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm using copies of the same parent UIVC, with different child UIVCs for each screen. As far as I can tell, the problem is that the container view controller has focus instead of child view controller, and the question was about how to give the child VC focus.

Comment: The child VC is being added manually so that may be related to something in FB not getting called, but my code is just boilerplate for adding a child VC manually.

Comment: Hmm. If a VC is instantiated and the user can interact with it, it will have 'focus'. It sounds like your hierarchy is messed up or perhaps controllers are being presented modally or maybe the ordering is not what is expected? What I would do is craft a snippet of code to print the view order to console - that way you can see which one is 'on top' and 'has focus'. That may lead to additional info.

Comment: Are you keeping strong or weak references to the viewControllers being instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

In the doc, it says

> If your app uses a distinct UIViewController or Activity for each
> screen, Analytics can automatically track every screen transition and
> generate a report of user engagement broken down by screen.

So in other words screen_view events apparently aren't sent automatically for nested UIViewControllers.

Comment: Don't overlook this *If your app uses a **distinct** UIViewController for each screen, Analytics can automatically track every screen transition* I believe though that have to be strong references so they are not memory dumped.